# How do i achieve Multisite routing in statamic

Tags: php, statamic

I have a multisite setup with a page collection that looks like this

```
title: Pages
sites:
  - TypischAtopisch
  - TypischHeuschnupfen
  - TypischNeurodermitis
propagate: false
template: default
layout: layout
revisions: false
route: '{parent_uri}/{slug}/'
sort_dir: asc
structure:
  root: true
```

the page collection folder looks like the image below,

[image]
I expect to be able to visit each page (e.g community) via a URL like `/community` however I get an error (second image) [image]. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned on discord, it looks like you're tying to get a global that doesn't exist